# Looking to start SharePoint alert after a field change in InfoPath Form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Good Morning,

I have a Form Library on my SharePoint site. On my form I have a calculated string field that does basic math (field1 x 3). I'm looking to have some way for the form to recognize that the field was changed (when saved) and somehow set off a SharePoint alert.

I'm completely baffled as how to go about this, if anyone could help that would be awesome! Thanks!
Shannon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways of doing this.

If you don't have programming access.

Create a new column, hidden if you want.  In SPD create a workflow to run when a change is made.  In that workflow compare the current value to the the that new column and if different then sent out email and copy the current value to this new column.

Or do the same thing in Infopath, if you have programming access, where when the form is opened you store the current value and when they save the form compare values and send out email as needed or set another column to sent out email and have a workflow do the mailing out.

If you have programming access to Sharepoint you could write your own handler to duplicate it, little more control.

Comment: I didn't even think about having Infopath store the current value when the form was opened, that solves a lot of problems!

Thanks so much, Will! :)